# Observe as state returns the initial value first jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a viewModel which turns a flow (from jetpack datastore) to a livedata:

**ViewModel**

```
val selectedTheme = dataStorage.getSelectedTheme().asLiveData()
```

In my composable:

**MainActivity**

```
setContent {
   val darkTheme = viewModel.selectedTheme.observeAsState(initial = false)
   Log.e("isDartThemeOn", darktheme.value.toString)
}
```

**LOGCAT**

1. false
2. darktheme.value

The initial value is first printed first before the actual observed value.

Note, if I dont supply an initial value, like this:

```
setContent {
   val darkTheme = viewModel.selectedTheme.observeAsState()
   Log.e("isDartThemeOn", darktheme.value.toString)
}
```

it returns:

1. null
2. darktheme.value

I only want the ***darktheme.value*** to be printed, without the initial value in ***observeAsState(false)***

This causes a weird ux.

Comment: `observeAsState` observes the value of the `LiveData`. Observation is an async work. If you provide initial data, it will be used as the placeholder value till the actual value is fetched. If you don't provide an initial value, `null` is taken as the default initial value. But, you can not change this behavior of `Flow`, `LiveData`, or `State` observation.

Comment: This does not occur when I was using viewModel.selectedTheme.observe(this) in xml projects

Only 1 value is returned..not null or initial/defaultvalue

Comment: @Ibramazin, I would only provide assumptions here, "This does not occur when I was using viewModel.selectedTheme.observe(this) in xml projects", keep in mind in jetpack compose, the burden of handling `states` is upon us (being declarative), one of the things I learned and notice in jetpack compose, is when you see something that has a `state` word in it, never assume that the framework will provide you a default state until you explicitly tell it should.

Comment: @Ibramazin, by calling this `viewModel.selectedTheme.observeAsState()` without specifying anything and called inside a `@composable` scope, as far I understand, you essentially tell the `composer` that you didn't provide any initial state, therefore the `composable` doesn't know where it should start. This is my mental model now learning compose, when I see a word `State` in a type I'm dealing with, I always assume that I MUST set its initial state